# Can you collect(joining()) without mapping to string?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am reading java 8 in action, and the author says that if you have a class that overrides the toString method, you don't need to map the stream to Strings when doing collect(joining()). An example:

```
    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<Person> people =
        Arrays.asList(
                new Person(23, "Paul"),
                new Person(23, "John"),
                new Person(23, "Greg"),
                new Person(24, "Greg"),
                new Person(25, "Paul")
        ); // Person overrides toString

        String peopleString = people
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.joining());

        System.out.println(peopleString);

    }
```

However, this doesn't work, and only this:

```
String peopleString = people
                .stream()
                .map(Person::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

works, so the book is wrong then? Besides, why does he say (I changed the wording a little):

> Also note that if a class had a toString method returning a string, you’d obtain the same result without needing to map over the original stream with a function extracting the name.

When every object is supposed to inherit `toString` from `Object`?

Comment: You do not need instead to create a method `toString()` in `Person` object ?

Comment: In which page you read this?

Comment: The only reason why something like `System.out.println(object)` prints the `toString` is because they implemented it like that. They offer a method which accepts `Object` instead of `String` and explicitly call `toString` on it. The `Collectors.joining()` however creates a `Collector<CharSequence, ?, String>` which wants `CharSequence` and not `Object` in general. Of course you could easily create one that accepts `Object` and then uses `toString`. But the default one does not.

Comment: @YCF_L seems to be on page `166`: Chapter `6.2.3. Joining Strings`. The menu example...

Comment: @MarkoPacak read the sentence myself, *may be* the definition of `joining` the author is referring to was really old and was something like `public static Collector<?, ?, String>` that internally called `toString`...

Comment: @Eugene seems to be the only option, despite a bit strange

Comment: @MarkoPacak not really if you think that even the functional interfaces had different names in the very beginning...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whatever the book says is wrong and your interpretation is right (unless the point is entirely different and you did not get it)

```
people.stream()
```

will generate a `Stream<People>`, while `Collectors.joining` has a definition of:

```
public static Collector<CharSequence, ?, String> joining()
```

obviously this can't work as `Person` is not an instance of `CharSequence`.